# MVVM bind XML document to TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

After having read lots of quite similar posts, I can't make it work. My issue seems to take place in the Binding, but I don't see what's wrong. I'm using the MVVM pattern and I try to display a XML file into the TreeView of a UserControl.

Here is my View XAML code

```
<UserControl x:Class="OtdrQualifTools.View.EepromView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"              
             xmlns:app="clr-namespace:OtdrQualifTools"
             xmlns:v="clr-namespace:OtdrQualifTools.View"             
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             Background="#FF2D2D30" d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="1030">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate">
            <TextBlock x:Name="text" Text="?" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <Binding XPath="child::node()" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Text">
                    <Setter TargetName="text" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Value}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Element">
                    <Setter TargetName="text" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Name}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Document">
                    <Setter TargetName="text" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=DocumentName}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <!-- Test to load directly the XML file here in the resources -->
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData" XPath="*" Source="E:/Projects/Irma/blah blah blah/xmlFile.xml" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}" Content="Go" Margin="5" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TreeView Margin="10,50,10,10"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding XmlEeprom}"
                  ItemTemplate= "{StaticResource NodeTemplate}"/>
        <!-- Use this part works!
        <TreeView Margin="10,50,10,10"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData}, XPath=*}"
                  ItemTemplate= "{StaticResource NodeTemplate}"/>
        -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the ViewModel class

```
   public class EepromViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
   {
      private System.Windows.Data.XmlDataProvider _xmlEeprom;
      public System.Windows.Data.XmlDataProvider XmlEeprom
      {
         get { return this._xmlEeprom; }
         set { this._xmlEeprom = value; OnPropertyChanged("XmlEeprom"); }
      }
      protected override void Start()
      {
         System.Windows.Data.XmlDataProvider dataProvider = new System.Windows.Data.XmlDataProvider();

         dataProvider.Source = new Uri(@"E:\Projects\Irma\blah blah blah\xmlFile.xml");
         dataProvider.IsInitialLoadEnabled = true;
         dataProvider.IsAsynchronous = false;
         dataProvider.XPath = "*";

//         //Test with XmlDocument directly faild too 
//         XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
//         xmlDoc .LoadXml(
//               @"<root>
//                    <child1>text1</child1>
//                    <child2>text2</child2>
//                  </root>");
//         dataProvider.Document = xmlDoc ;
         this.XmlEeprom = dataProvider;
      }
   }
```

When I trace into the code, the DataProvider is well loaded, the document is present. Why is it not displayed in the treeView ?

Comment: I don't know which component are you using. Is it telerik ? Are your model properties  notifiable (implement INotifyPropertyChanged) ? Check this.

Comment: What's more your `Enumerable` Items must support ICollectionChange , it can be something like ObservableCollection

Comment: My ViewModel implement the INotifyPropertyChanged, its works for sure. I'm trying to bind the XmlDataProvider in the ViewModel to the ItemsSource of the TreeView, but it does not work...

Comment: Any binding errors in Output window?

Comment: Sadly no... The first place I verified

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution (by chance!).

I simply change the binding from

```
<TreeView Margin="10,50,10,10"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding XmlEeprom}"
                  ItemTemplate= "{StaticResource NodeTemplate}"/>
```

to

```
<TreeView Margin="10,50,10,10"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding XmlEeprom.Document}"
                  ItemTemplate= "{StaticResource NodeTemplate}"/>
```

Now its works like a charm !